# Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin doesnt work?

Tags: node.js, azure, cors

I am trying to get my head around the CORS settings for my rest api on azure

```
'use strict';
var debug = require('debug');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
//var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.use(cors());
```

doesnt seem to work, any options/or am I missing something?

Comment: Its the same as what I posted. No update. At the moment cant accept it sorry.

Comment: What the error message do you get? what the meaning of not work?

Comment: Its the same as , No Access Control origin is present on the requested resource, 

I discovered , adding the below lines, on the router resolved the error

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();

Answer (score 0):

I test in my site with the following code and it works very well with the cors in response header.

```
var cors = require('cors');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.use(cors());

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var data = {
        "Fruits": [
          "apple",
          "orange"    ]
      };
      res.json(data);
   });
app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 3000')
});
```

[image]